# How to differentiate tags related to the word "idle"?

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

I wanted to survey the StackOverflow posts which discussed various ways of doing idle processing, which would be when either the cpu or user wasn't doing anything else.  (People are always wanting to hold of certain computations until they're sure the user isn't trying to do anything, and then quickly return control and cancel that work if they do).

When I clicked on the "idle" tag I got a lot of things about a Python IDE called "IDLE".  I think it's a rather silly name considering that it stands for "I nteractive D eve L opment E nvironment".

I tagged those questions as "idle-ide" (since they all had the python tag already, it seemed better than "python-idle".  After all, there are questions about doing idle-time processing in python too).

But I'm worried that if there's a tag for idle at all, people will use it for the IDE.  So perhaps "idle-time" is the better choice to replace "idle"?  (already existed)  Or "idle-processing" (which is probably what I would have made).

Also is IMAP IDLE another category?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE

Comment: The CAPTCHA I got when posting this was "idles NJ" (which is not the first eerily non-random one of those I've gotten).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I share your worry against using just [idle] to describe idle processing, because [idle] doesn't even mean idle processing on its own. Considering that there are other uses within programming for idle, then it is even more pertinent in my eyes to remove it, because leaving the root of an ambiguous tag simply leaves more opportunity for people to misuse it later. Leaving ambiguous tags just leaves more diluted search results, which is of no help to anyone.

I haven't used Python's IDLE, so I don't know whether people would find it easier with [idle-ide] or [python-idle]. I'll be watching this question to see what the consensus is, which may lend some insight on how to solve the [C++ temporary problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49561/).

To that end, I would pick [idle-processing]. It sounds more on-target than [idle-time] does, even if they're functionally equivalent for tagging purpose.